# Java form search method not working - (Cannot fine the Member_ID from the database member table)

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

i have a class call member
i have a method call " public member searchByName(String key) " in membermanager class
i have another jFrame which has a search button(type mouse click)

inside my member database there is a member call 123(Member_ID)/ Primary key

when i insert 123 and search from java UI it says "No member found"

please check my coding and help me to fix this problem, Thank you ALL! :) [database (lmsjason- table member)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Zxv.jpg)

```
package UIDesignLMS;


public class member {

    private String m_memberid;
    private String m_membername;
    private String m_dob;
    private String m_address;
    private String m_contact;

    public member(){


    }

    public member(String memberid, String membername, String dob, String address, String contact){
        m_memberid = memberid;
        m_membername = membername;
        m_dob = dob;
        m_address = address;
        m_contact = contact;

    }
    public void setId(String memberid){
        m_memberid = memberid;
    }
    public String getId(){
        return m_memberid;
    }
    public void setName(String membername){
        m_membername = membername;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return m_membername;
    }
    public void setDob(String dob){
        m_dob = dob;
    }
    public String getDob(){
        return m_dob;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address){
        m_address = address;
    }
    public String getAddress(){
        return m_address;
    }
    public void setContact(String contact){
        m_membername = contact;
    }
    public String getContact(){
        return m_contact;
    }



}
```

```css
package UIDesignLMS;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class membermanager {

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet re = null;  

    private ViewMemberUI view;

    public membermanager() {
        //load the database driver
        conn = MysqlConnect.ConnectDB();
    }



    public member searchByName(String key) {
        Connection conn;

        member Member = new member();
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lmsjason","root","");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from member where Member_ID like '%\" + key + \"%' ");
            while (rs.next()) {

                Member = new member(rs.getString("Member_ID"), rs.getString("Name"),rs.getString("DOB"),rs.getString("Address"),rs.getString("Contact"));

            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        return Member;
    }
  }
```

```html
private void jLabel7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // Search
        if ("".equals(textmemberid.getText())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Member ID cannot be empty");

        } else {
            member Member = manager.searchByName(textmemberid.getText());
            if (Member.getId() == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Member found!");
            } else {
                textname.setText(Member.getName());
                textdob.setText(Member.getDob());
                textaddress.setText(Member.getAddress());
                textcontact.setText(Member.getContact());


            }

        }
    }    

/*
 * Data Base Connection
 */
package UIDesignLMS;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class MysqlConnect {
    Connection conn=null;
    public static Connection ConnectDB(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lmsjason","root","");
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to database");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for using a debugger.

Comment: You are escaping the quotes `...'%\" + key + \"%'...` it should be `...'%" + key + "%'...` but you're better off using a `PreparedStatement` instead of String concatenation.

Comment: Thanks bro it works now :) yeah i have to learn about Preparestatment more

Answer (score 0):

Why you Simply don't use `PrepapredStatement` it is more helpful and more secure  example :

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lmsjason", "root", "");
PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from member where Member_ID like ? ");
stm.setString(1, key);
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    Member = new member(rs.getString("Member_ID"), rs.getString("Name"), 
             rs.getString("DOB"), rs.getString("Address"), rs.getString("Contact"));

}
```

You don't need to set quotes `''` with `PrepapredStatement`

You can take a look at [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Thanks brother Titus answer is working and yes i will learn more about Preparestatement

Comment: you are welcome @TECKid don't forgot to accept the answer